# How to iterate over a series with identical indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am looking to iterate over a series that contains groups of identical indices. The data looks like:

```
0      -0.969886
0      -0.941016
0      -0.913815
0      -0.888142
0      -0.863872
      ...   
3423   -0.841284
3423   -0.840156
3423   -0.839032
3423   -0.837911
3423   -0.836792
Length: 13828, dtype: object
```

The following is the for loop code:

```
ln_gamma_i = []
ln_gamma_j = []
for i in range(len(tau_21)):
    ln_gamma_i.append(x2**2 * (tau_21[i] * (g_21[i]/(x1 + x2 * g_21[i]))**2 + tau_12[i] * 
                      g_12[i]/(x2 + x1 * g_12[i])**2))
    ln_gamma_j.append(x1**2 * (tau_12[i] * (g_12[i]/(x2 + x1 * g_12[i]))**2 + tau_21[i] * 
                      g_21[i]/(x1 + x2 * g_21[i])**2))
```

tau_21 is equal in length to tau_12, g_21 and g_12. I can't simply compute the equation without a for loop because x1 and x2 are of size = 5. So there are 5 outputs to each iteration.
How can I iterate over the rows rather than the indices. I realize there is iterrows or iteritems but from what I understand those seem to help for 1 series, here I have 4 different series.

Comment: To get a list of unique indices you can use `idx = set(df['col'].tolist())`. then you can iterate over the elements of idx using `df.where` to get all elements with this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use zip to create a tupple of the two iterators ans loop trough both:

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[9,8,7]
c=zip(a,b)
for i,n in c:
    print(str(i) +" " + str(n))

... 
1 9
2 8
3 7
```

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: Its seems that I can only perform operations within print (eg. print(i+2) etc.), however, I can't append the results (eg. empty_list.append(i+2) which returns empty_list = []). The append worked for you code, which are lists, the data I have are series.